# No such operator "[]" matches these operands

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I am trying to make a program that demonstrates use of templates and overloaded operators for my CS class. Here is relevant code:

main:

```
    ArrayTemplate<int> number(0);
            number[0] = 1;
            number[1] = 2;
            number[2] = 3;

    ArrayTemplate<string> word("na");
            word[0] = "One";
            word[1] = "Two";
            word[2] = "Three";
```

header:

```
template<class T>
T& operator [](const int index) 
{ 
    if(index >= 0 && index < ARRAY_MAX_SIZE)
        return items[index];
    else
    {
        cerr << "INDEX OUT OF BOUNDS!!!";
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I try to use my overloaded subscript operator I get the error message shown in title: "No such operator "[]" matches these operands" Im not exactly sure why. It does it for both my integer array and my string array. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What's the type of `items`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *really* need to show the full definition of `ArrayTemplate`.

This is how you probably want it to look:

```
template<class T>
class ArrayTemplate {
  public:

    // ...

    T& operator [](const int index) 
    { 
        if(index >= 0 && index < ARRAY_MAX_SIZE)
            return items[index];
        else
        {
            cerr << "INDEX OUT OF BOUNDS!!!";
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    // ...
};
```

Note that `operator[]` isn't templated; only the class is.

With your current code you would have to do it like this:

```
number<int>[0] = 1;
number<int>[1] = 2;
number<int>[2] = 3;
```

Which obviously goes against your intention.

Comment: Than you for the explanation. I didnt realize I didnt need to template the operator. Removing that line fixed the program and it works as intended.

Answer (score 1):

```
template<class T>
T& operator [](const int index)
```

This declaration would be called e.g. as `object.operator[] < type >( 5 )`. Note that `type` needs to be provided as a template argument. Because there's no way to supply such an argument in an expression using `[]`, the operator overload doesn't work.

Probably you don't want the `template< class T >` at all. Just get rid of it:

```
T& operator [](const int index)
```

If you define the function outside the `class {}` scope, then it would look like this:

```
template<class T>
T& ArrayTemplate<T>::operator [](const int index)
```

In this case, the `template<class T>` line re-introduces the parameter in order to get back into the class template.